# i try to download games on my tablet and it keeps saying no space on device

Tags: google-play-store

I try to download games and it always say insufficient space on device what should I do. Google play or play store

Answer (score 1):

You should ocassionally go to Settings -> Storage -> Cached Data and clear it, because over time it could use up more than a GB of storage. Of course, no need to do it to often as Android uses it to find data faster, only when it gets to big.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "settings" and then "Storage", you'll see how much 'System Space' is left. You can uninstall useless app to make room for the game or go to "Files" and cleanup junk folders and files.